# How can I allow a frame to be moved up and down in WinRT?

Tags: windows-runtime, slide, gesture

I'm struggling with touch support in WinRT.

I have a Canvas with a Frame that contains a TextBlock. The TextBlock can have varying amounts of text which could make the Frame extend below the bottom of the Canvas. If that happens, I want the user to be able to touch the Frame and move it up so they can finish reading the text. If they move the Frame all the way up, it should stop when the bottom of the Frame is a set margin from the bottom of the Canvas. Same for moving it back down. Using the Inertia capabilities would be preferred as well.

If anyone can offer some direction, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend wrapping a ScrollViewer around your textblock enabling the user to scroll on the screen to see all the text.

```
<ScrollViewer>
     <TextBlock Content="Very long content goes here" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

For **additional** information check these sites out:

[Link to the scrollviewer in the control list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465351.aspx#s_section)

[Link to the scrollviewer documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.aspx)

Comment: That would be how a traditional non-touch windows app would work. A touch interface should not work that way. The user should just touch the block and move it up and down.

Comment: I guess, it really depends on what app and UI you are creating. In case one would want to use the scrollviewer but doesn't like scrollbar UI when scrolling, it can be hidden by changing the default template and setting it's the opacity to 0, while preserving the visibility of the contentpresenter.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...

```
<Canvas x:Name="MainCanvas" ManipulationMode="TranslateRailsX" IsRightTapEnabled="False" IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" Margin="50,50,716,0" Width="600" ManipulationDelta="MainFrame_ManipulationDelta_1">
    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform x:Name="ScrollMain"></CompositeTransform>
    </Canvas.RenderTransform>
    <Frame x:Name="MainFrame" Background="Beige" Height="auto" Width="600">
        <RichTextBlock x:Name="MainContent" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18" FontFamily="Segoe Script" Width="540" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,10,0,10" Foreground="Black" Height="auto" IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" IsHoldingEnabled="False" IsRightTapEnabled="False" IsTapEnabled="False" ManipulationMode="None" IsTextSelectionEnabled="False"/>
    </Frame>
</Canvas>

MainCanvas.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.TranslateY | ManipulationModes.TranslateRailsY | ManipulationModes.TranslateInertia;

private void MainFrame_ManipulationDelta_1(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CompositeTransform transform = ScrollMain as CompositeTransform;

    double yDelta = e.Delta.Translation.Y;
    double bDelta = (MainFrame.ActualHeight - pageRoot.ActualHeight + MainCanvas.Margin.Top + MainCanvas.Margin.Top) * -1;

    if (transform.TranslateY + yDelta > 0)
    {
        yDelta = transform.TranslateY * -1;
    }

    if (transform.TranslateY + yDelta < bDelta)
    {
        transform.TranslateY = bDelta;
    }
    else
    {
        transform.TranslateY += yDelta;
    }

    base.OnManipulationDelta(e);
}
```

Comment: I do have one issue...I can only move the Frame from the edge of the canvas...if I touch the textblock area, nothing happens...so I need to figure out how to send the textblock touches to the frame.